# How To Improve Role & Permission Performance In Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

IF I have 4 tables 'roles','permissions','users','role_permission' each user have role and each role hasmany permissions stored role_id and permission_id at role_permission table .
The Topic is the permissions table loaded at each blade to check if authenticated user have permission to this blade or not how can improve the performance and solve this problem 'at each blade the all permissions loaded from database'.

[debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHiZh.png)

How to improve performance and not load all permissions

Answer (score 0):

You can define gates for each permission and then use Laravel's @can directive in blades.
in `AuthServiceProvider` boot function:

```
Gate::define('edit-posts', function ($user) {
    return $user->hasPermission('edit-posts');
});
```

in any blade:

```
@can('edit-posts')
    //
@endcan
```

Comment: i'am use gates already for checking if user has this permission at controllers & requests & blades my question is how make permissions loaded only one time and not loaded in each blade at system

Comment: Did you try to cache them with cache() method?